# how to convert mindmap csv to python dict and find key

Tags: python

here is the mindmap
[image]

and corresponding csv file is
`history,Africa,Egyptian,pyramid
,Asia,Ancient India,Caste System
,,,Buddhism
,Eourp,Greece,xxx
,,Rome,yyy
,,,zzzz`
I want to convert csv file to json like struct

```
{
    'history': [
        {
            'Africa': [
                {
                    'Egyptian': [{'pyramid': []}]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            'Asia': [
                {
                    'Ancient India': [
                        {'Caste System': []},
                        {'Buddhism': []}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

finally a function to find the key and print the path of that key
e.g. `find('Buddhism') -> history.Asia.Ancient India.Buddhism`

I've tried Tree but I have no idea how to achieve this.

Comment: Where are you stuck with your implementation? Showing a [MCVE] of your attempt would help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution:

```
# Load your string into list of list
m = []
for each in s.split('\n'):
    l = each.split(',')
    m.append(l)

# Create dict object that you want.
master = {}
level_indexes = [-1]*10
for i in range(len(m)):
    level = len([e for e in m[i] if e == ''])
    level_indexes[level] = i
    level_indexes[level+1:] = [-1]*(10-level-1)
    if level == 0:
        head = master
        for each in m[i]:
            head[each] = {}
            head = head[each]
    else:
        head = master
        indexes = []
        for j, e in enumerate(level_indexes[:level]):
            if e is not -1:
                indexes.append(j)
        indexes.append(level)
        last = []
        for j in range(len(indexes)-1):
            last.extend(m[level_indexes[j]][indexes[j]:indexes[j+1]])
        for j in range(level):
            head = head[last[j]]
        for j in range(level, len(m[i])):
            head[m[i][j]] = {}
            head = head[m[i][j]]
```

This creates a nested dictionary - `master`:

```
{'history': {'Africa': {'Egyptian': {'pyramid': {}}},
             'Asia': {'Ancient India': {'Buddhism': {}, 'Caste System': {}}},
             'Eourp': {'Greece': {'xxx': {}},
                       'Rome': {'yyy': {}, 'zzzz': {}}}}}
```

If you tweak it a little bit, you can put everything in list, but that will make it much more complicated:

```
master = []
level_indexes = [-1]*10
for i in range(len(m)):
    level = len([e for e in m[i] if e == ''])
    level_indexes[level] = i
    level_indexes[level+1:] = [-1]*(10-level-1)
    if level == 0:
        head = master
        for each in m[i]:
            head.append({each: []})
            head = head[-1][each]
    else:
        head = master
        indexes = []
        for j, e in enumerate(level_indexes[:level]):
            if e is not -1:
                indexes.append(j)
        indexes.append(level)
        last = []
        for j in range(len(indexes)-1):
            last.extend(m[level_indexes[j]][indexes[j]:indexes[j+1]])
        for j in range(level):
            head = head[-1][last[j]]
        for j in range(level, len(m[i])):
            head.append({m[i][j]: []})
            head = head[-1][m[i][j]]
```

output:

```
[{'history': [{'Africa': [{'Egyptian': [{'pyramid': []}]}]},
              {'Asia': [{'Ancient India': [{'Caste System': []},
                                           {'Buddhism': []}]}]},
              {'Eourp': [{'Greece': [{'xxx': []}]},
                         {'Rome': [{'yyy': []}, {'zzzz': []}]}]}]}]
```